# Including two separate figures in latex as a subplot

Tags: subfloats

I have two separate figures in tex file: fig1.tex and fig2.tex
for example

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
.
.
.
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

I use `\input{fig1.tex}` and `\input{fig2.tex}` to include them in `main.tex` as two separate figures

How to include them in one figure as subplots?

Comment: BTW, this is an extremely inefficient way to do things.  Try using standalone to test/develop new images and add the captions in the main document.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to temporarily redefine `figure` to be `subfigure`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{fig1}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Hello world!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{fig2}
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{photo}
\caption{caption}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\bgroup
  \renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{\subfigure{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}}{\endsubfigure}
  \input{fig1}\hfill
  \input{fig2}
\egroup
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: thank you for your answer but the figures are not generated although no errors appears

Comment: I had `\textwidth` misspelled, but other than than it works fine for me.  Is photo not supposed to be a Simpson?

Comment: I changed it to \begin{tikzpicture} instead of \includegraphics{photo} and i would like to have them at the same horizontal

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you after. Probably something like this?

[image]

This can be simply to obtain by use of minipages, in which you insert for example `tikzpicture` by use of `\input{<file name>}` and some image on the same way (however, in such cases is simpler to insert it directly by using `includegraphics`). Of course, each minipage should contain `\caption` and `\label` too:

```
\begin{filecontents}{fig-a}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{Hello world!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{fig-b}
\includegraphics{photo}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\input{fig-a}%\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{caption}
    \label{fig-a}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
                          \input{fig-b}
                          \caption{caption}
                          \label{fig-b}
                         \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
See figure \ref{fig-a} and \ref{fig-b} ...

\end{document}
```